# Lead generation from social studio

Tags: leads, socialpost, radian6

I have read that leads can be ***manually*** created via Social Hub (document link: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/radian6/en-us/static/pdf/Radian6EngagementConsole.pdf) by adding the Salesforce Extension. 
I am assuming that leads can also be automatically created somehow (dont think engagement macros can be used as it seems (from documentation) that it can be used only for creating cases). Could you please advice if this is possible.

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you need to setup Social Customer Service ([documents](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/5/en-us/sfdc/pdf/social_customer_service_impl_guide.pdf)) - then you would need to modify the standard Apex Code supplied to create a lead instead of a contact linked to the Social Persona created for the Social Account.

Default behaviour is

> The default Apex class for Social Customer Service creates a social post, social persona, case, contact,
>   and supports common use cases. To customize how information is processed, by create a new
>   Apex class.

By modifying the supplied code and selecting the new class in setup

> The default Apex class sets the contact as the persona parent. To set the persona parent as an account, person account, or lead, create
>   a method to override the persona parent.